# Use recursion to match Strings with wildcards

Tags: java, recursion, wildcard

Sorry if this is long but please bear with me. I'm trying to check, with recursion, if 2 strings are the same (which I was able to do by essential chopping off parts of the String) and have special cases for wildcards:

Which I can't get for the life of me, I tried to check if `'@'` exists and calling the function again and a similar idea for the asterix but I can't get it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can compare chars to literals by using the '' (single quotes) operators rather than the "" (double quotes) operators.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just showing relevant part of the code:

```
else if (c1String.equals("@") || c2String.equals("@")) {
            return areTheSame(x.substring(1), y.substring(1));
        }

        else if (c1String.equals("*") || c2String.equals("*")){
            return true;
        }
```

I have simply replaced (==) with .equals for string. This takes care of your first two cases.

== checks for reference equality which you do not require. You need to check if the values are same and hence the use of .equals method for string comparison.

I advise you to read java documentation on this for further clarity.

Third is a special case and you need to take care of it explicitly as

```
else if (x.length() == 0 && y.length() != 0 || y.length() == 0
            && x.length() != 0) {
        return false;
    }
```

this code block forces to return false. [You will need to handle your special case in this if block and force to return true for the third case.]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the reply :). Do you have any tips/hints you can give me for the 3rd case?

Comment: Yes. In the else if block(where you are currently just returning false) just add a condition for your special case. Pick the non zero length string and check if it has all characters as '*'. If it does then return true else return false.